# input type datetime-local should appear as my local timezone

Tags: javascript

I have an `<input type="datetime-local"/>`

I live in timezone UTC+1.

If I select 24.12.2022: 12:00, the `onChange => currentTarget.valueAsDate`, it shows me:

`Sat Dec 24 2022 13:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

This means the input form itself is assuming I am entering UTC time, and it will convert it to my local timezone.

How can I make the `<input/>` appear as my local timezone?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const input = document.querySelector('your input');

input.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const date = event.currentTarget.valueAsDate;
  const formattedDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'UTC+1' });
  console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'UTC+1' }));
  input.value = formattedDate;
});
```

This code, will update the value of the input to the formatted date string in your local timezone (UTC+1).
However, the toLocaleString method may not work in all browsers, so as an alternative moment.js(https://momentjs.com/) library can  handle date and time formatting if you need wider browser support.